# Older battle videos in Pokémon Sun/Moon say they can't be viewed

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I have about 25 battle videos after a epic finish to a battle with someone I saved the new battle video.

I wanted to view all of my battle videos but when I went to my older battle videos they don't work they say this video can't be viewed (or something like that). it does this even if I am connected to the internet and I never deleted any.

how do I get them back?

Comment: Were they uploaded to the web (where you get a battle code) or only stored locally?

Answer (score 2):

You probably saved those videos some time ago, before updating your game to version 1.1 or 1.2. The problem is that, after updating your game to one of those versions, you are not able to watch your old videos anymore. It is mentionned in the [patch notes](https://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/patch.shtml) for both of those updates:

> **Notes**
>
> Battle Videos recorded before this patch can no longer be viewed

The only way to see those videos again would be to get back to the version of the game when you did the corresponding battles. You should then probably try to record them with some external sources so you can watch those later again, before updating back to the current version.

Some users performed it on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokeMoonSun/comments/5ng0l9/why_cant_i_watch_battle_videos/?st=j3cmy5d8&sh=3a63eacb), and apparently it worked well for them:

> I was wondering if it was safe too so I deleted the update I had on Moon. Sun's my main and it has a lot of stuff on it while Moon is a new save file so I had less to risk with it.
> Not only is it perfectly safe to remove the update data, after doing it I was also able to access the old Battle Videos afterwards as well.

Comment: Does this mean that a possible workaround is to have both games and just keep one game unpatched? Can you watch battle videos recorded in Sun on Moon and vice versa?

Comment: @Robotnik A possible workaround would indeed to have both versions of the game with one remaining in the same version than the one used when the videos have been saved. Then, as long as you have the corresponding code for the video, you just have to enter it from the "View Battle Video" in Festival Plaza, and it should do the trick, even if it's coming from the other game.